# Finding reference quaternion of a satellite in orbit

Tags: artificial-satellite, attitude, attitude-determination-and-control, quaternion

How can i find the reference [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) of a satellite after it has detumbled? I need the quaternion to be able to successfully actuate my payload, which in this case will be a [hyperspectral imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspectral_imaging) camera.

Comment: I've just added a [tag for quaternion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quaternion). There are a few other questions that have it as well. You can have a look at those, or just [search this site](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=quaternion) for quaternion to include more questions and answers.

Comment: If you don't receive any helpful answers, you might consider including a little more description of how you are de-tumbling, or where your ADCS information in the spacecraft is coming from.

Comment: You would need to provide better information on your attitude control system, at least on the available sensors. But to be clear: There is no analytical or numerical and reliable way to precisely determine attitude for a detumbled satellite in a simulation. You could get some dispersion metrics, but it could be just around anywhere. Most likely, you need magnetomers, sun sensors, star trackers and all this stuff to measure and then refine attitude knowledge onboard.